# How to specify absolute paths

Tags: paths

I input a file `inp.txt` using its path relative to the directory containing the `main.tex` file and where I will run `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \input{../inputs/inp.txt}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to specify the absolute path of `inp.txt`, e.g. `~/inputs/inp.txt`?

Since I am looking for a general solution to include `\includegraphics`, `\input` and `\include` files I try to use `TEXINPUTS` and modify my script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \input{inp.txt}
\end{document}
```

When I run

```
TEXINPUTS=~/inputs pdflatex main.tex
```

it turns out I have changed my working directory producing the error message:

```
! I can't find file `filepath.tex'.
```

Adding multiple paths `TEXINPUTS=~/inputs:.` produces other problems.

Is there a simple and concise solution?

Comment: just specify the path, eg `/users/someone/inputs/inp.txt`   if you want to use `~` use `\string~` otherwise it means nobreak space.

Comment: your TEXINPUTS setting has not changed the working directory but has removed all the standard directories from the path, you need a trailing `:`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just specify the path, eg

```
\input{/users/someone/inputs/inp.txt}
```

if you want to use `~` use `\string~` otherwise it means nobreak space.

```
\input{\string~/inputs/inp.txt}
```

---

(added after edit to question)

Your TEXINPUTS setting should be

```
 TEXINPUTS=.:~/inputs:
```

where the trailing `:` means to include the standard path.