# eps files outside the working directory

Tags: graphics, eps, paths

Consider the following `script.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{fig/epsfig.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When calling `pdflatex script.tex` a file `epsfig-eps-converted-to.pdf` gets generated in the folder `./fig`.

The affairs get complicated when the eps file is stored in a repository outside the working directory.

The options how to include an external directory were nicely discussed in [How to specify absolute paths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451222/how-to-specify-absolute-paths)

**1. Specifying the absolute path**

In case I write like this:

```
\includegraphics{\string~/repo/epsfig.eps}
```

the eps file (in contrast to a png file) is not found:

```
!!! Error: Cannot open ~/repo/epsfig.eps: No such file or directory
system returned with code 512
```

**2. Specifying TEXINPUTS**

The job gets done when calling:

```
TEXINPUTS=.:~/repo: pdflatex script.tex
```

and using

```
\includegraphics{epsfig.eps}
```

but the `-eps-converted-to.pdf` file is created in my working directory. Imagine I use 100 eps files.

**3. Specifying \graphicspath**

When using the

```
\graphicspath{\string~/repo}
```

as described in

[Multiple graphics directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224930/multiple-graphics-directory?answertab=active#tab-top)

the complaint of not finding the eps file disappears but the eps-converted-to-pdf file is not found:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `\unhbox\voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}epsfig-eps-c
onverted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

Is there an elegant solution?

Comment: define multiple image paths as shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224930/multiple-graphics-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple graphics directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224930/multiple-graphics-directory)

Comment: @naphaneal, it did not solve the problem: `! Package pdftex.def Error: File `\unhbox\voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}epsfig-eps-c
onverted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.`